# Why calling jQuery AJAX request with JSONP blocks ui on iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, jsonp

I'm using this next code to perform long polling in my webapp. the server is configured to respond to my requests with data I later parse with `onSuccessGetMessages`.

```
function getMessages() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: communicationInfo.urlToSend,
    timeout: communicationInfo.requestTimeout
  })
  .done(onSuccessGetMessages)
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("getMessages - failed");
    setTimeout(getMessages, communicationInfo.timeoutBetweenRequests);
  });
}
```

The problem is that while this is working great when running in desktop Chrome, on my iOS 6 iPad (chrome and safari) it causes the GUI animations and effects to act sluggish.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this report of ajax bugs in iOS6 help? http://www.devthought.com/2012/09/22/understanding-the-ios6-ajax-bugs/

Comment: Very interesting, but the unfortunate answer is no.